# Calendar in Fullcalendar is not showing long events/holidays

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) plugin.

This is my code for fullcalendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    timeZone        : 'Asia/Riyadh',
    header          : {
                        left: 'prev,next ',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay' // month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth
    },
    buttonText      : {
                        today: 'today',
                        month: 'month',
                        week : 'week',
                        day  : 'day'
    },
    themeSystem     : 'bootstrap4',
    //timeFormat      : 'H:mm',//(:mm)',
    weekNumbers     : false,
    navLinks        : true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable        : true,
    eventLimit      : false, // allow "more" link when too many events
    //eventColor      : '#43BADE',
    //eventTextColor  : '#ffffff',
    events          : eventsData,
    eventRender     : function(event, element) {

                        element.find(".fc-title").html('<span style="font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">' + event.title + '</span>');

                        var tooltipHtml = '<table>';

                            tooltipHtml += '<tr>';
                            tooltipHtml += '<td style="padding-bottom:5px;" colspan="2"><span style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold; line-height:1.2;">' + event.full_title + '</span></td>';
                            tooltipHtml += '</tr>';

                            tooltipHtml += '<tr>';
                            tooltipHtml += '<td style="font-size:13px;font-weight:600; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:5px;">Start:</td><td style="font-size:13px;">' + formatDate(event.start, 'dd-mm-YYYY') + '</td>';
                            tooltipHtml += '</tr>';

                            if(event.end != null)
                            {
                              tooltipHtml += '<tr>';
                              tooltipHtml += '<td style="font-size:13px;font-weight:600; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:5px;">End:</td><td style="font-size:13px;">' + formatDate(event.end, 'dd-mm-YYYY') + '</td>';
                              tooltipHtml += '</tr>';
                            }

                            tooltipHtml += '</table>';

                        element.qtip({  //show event description at qtip. qtip Plugin Location  : (plugins/fullcalender/)
                          content : tooltipHtml,
                          show    : {
                              event: 'click',
                              solo: true
                          },
                          hide: {
                              event: 'click unfocus'
                          }
                        });
    },
    viewRender       : function () {
                        var month = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate').month()+1;
                        if (month<10) 
                        {
                            selectedMonth = 0+''+month;
                        } else{
                            selectedMonth = month;
                        }
                        var currentMonth = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate').year()+'-'+selectedMonth;
                        //sessionList(currentMonth); //month wise session list
    },
    select          : function(start, end) {
                        if(start.isBefore(moment())) {
                            
                        }
    },
    dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
    }
  });
```

This is my code of how I am building up the events array which contains holidays:-

```
for(var event = 0; event < data.data.length; event++)
{   
  if(data.data[event].end == null)
  {
    strDateObj  = new Date(data.data[event].start);
    eventsData.push({
            title           : (data.data[event].title !== '' && data.data[event].title !== null) ? ((data.data[event].title.length > 25) ? data.data[event].title.substring(0, 25) + '...' : data.data[event].title) : 'N/A',
            //title           : data.data[event].title,
            full_title      : data.data[event].title,
            start           : strDateObj,
            startStr        : strDateObj.toISOString(),
            allDay          : true,
            backgroundColor : '#f56954', //red
            borderColor     : '#f56954' //red
        });
  }
  else
  {
    strDateObj  = new Date(data.data[event].start);
    endDateObj  = new Date(data.data[event].end);
    eventsData.push({
            title           : (data.data[event].title !== '' && data.data[event].title !== null) ? ((data.data[event].title.length > 25) ? data.data[event].title.substring(0, 25) + '...' : data.data[event].title) : 'N/A',
            //title           : data.data[event].title,
            full_title      : data.data[event].title,
            start           : strDateObj,
            startStr        : strDateObj.toISOString(),
            end             : endDateObj,
            endStr          : endDateObj.toISOString(),
            allDay          : true,
            backgroundColor : '#f56954', //red
            borderColor     : '#f56954' //red
        });
  }
}
```

I have a holiday called Eid Holiday which is starting on 29th March, 2022 and ending on 30th March, 2022.

But in the calendar view, only 29th March is showing the **Eid Holiday** event while 30th March is blank.

[image]

Why is this happening? How can I show Eid Holiday as a long Holiday extended on 30th March too?

Answer (score 0):

For **multi-day** `allday: true` events, we have to add a day on to the end date to get them to show in our calendar.

So in your `else` block, try:

```
end: endDateObj.setDate(endDateObj.getDate() + 1)
```

For your tooltip to stay correct, add a new property `endOriginal` when you build your events data

```
eventsData.push({
    ...
    endOriginal: endDateObj,
    ...
});
```

Then change your `tooltip` builder to use that

```
/* FullCalendar v5 */
if(event.extendedProps.endOriginal != null) {
  tooltipHtml += '<tr>';
  tooltipHtml += '<td style="font-size:13px;font-weight:600; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:5px;">End:</td><td style="font-size:13px;">' + formatDate(event.extendedProps.endOriginal, 'dd-mm-YYYY') + '</td>';
  tooltipHtml += '</tr>';
}

/* or */

/* FullCalendar v3 */
if(event.endOriginal != null) {
  tooltipHtml += '<tr>';
  tooltipHtml += '<td style="font-size:13px;font-weight:600; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:5px;">End:</td><td style="font-size:13px;">' + formatDate(event.endOriginal, 'dd-mm-YYYY') + '</td>';
  tooltipHtml += '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Yes, I also thought the same but it had another issue in my case. See the screenshot I shared? There is a yellow tooltip showing Start and End of the holiday. When I used your solution, the end date becomes 31st March, instead of 30th March.

Comment: Indeed, we have a solution for that too @Saswat. Add a new property `endOriginal` and base the `tooltip` on that. I have amended my answer to show you.